Can regression coefficients be bootstrapped when sampling weights must be used?
I have non-complex survey data - it has sample weights but nothing else about the survey design to be taken into account. I want to get bootstrap distributions for regression coefficients, using the weights. I want the bootstrap mainly for calculating confidence intervals (CIs) with fewer assumptions.
I find loads of literature (and implementations) for weighted regression, and loads about bootstrapping, but I find almost nothing about combining the two. My instinct is to try like this: create bootstrap samples using the sampling weights to weight the bootstrap sampling, make a non-weighted model for each bootstrap sample, and then I have my collection of bootstrapped coefficients. But I have a nagging feeling that this approach doesn't sufficiently penalise the CIs. My error should be larger when I used weights - but it won't be like this (or will it?)?

Short Answer
The standard approach is to create bootstrap replicate samples for your data, using a bootstrap method appropriate to your survey design. Then you estimate the coefficients separately with each bootstrap sample, and calculate the variance of the estimates across the bootstrap samples. The square root of that variance estimate gives you a standard error estimate $se(\hat{\beta})$.
For the $1-\alpha$ confidence interval, you can use a symmetric confidence interval like the following:
$$\hat{\beta} \pm se(\hat{\beta}) \times t_{df, 1-\alpha/2}$$
The $t$ statistic is the $1-\alpha/2$ quantile from a $t$ distribution with $df$ degrees of freedom. For a sample without any stratification or clustering, the degrees of freedom would probably be something like $n-1$, but the appropriate value to use depends on your sample design. The 'survey' package in R has some reasonable methods for figuring all that out for you.
That's the approach most commonly used for survey data. Other bootstrap confidence interval methods could potentially be used (e.g., bootstrap percentile confidence intervals), but their performance for complex survey data is not well understood yet (see the Mashreghi et al. 2017 reference below).
Details
The Lumley and Scott (2017) paper contains a good overview of how to fit regression models with weighted survey data.

Thomas Lumley. Alastair Scott. "Fitting Regression Models to Survey Data." Statist. Sci. 32 (2) 265 - 278, May 2017. https://doi.org/10.1214/16-STS605

The methods described in that paper are available in the 'survey' package in R:

Lumley T (2024). “survey: analysis of complex survey samples.” R package version 4.4. https://doi.org/10.32614/CRAN.package.survey

The overview paper by Mashreghi et al. (2016) contains a good overview of bootstrap methods for survey data and what is known about bootstrap confidence interval methods for survey data:

Mashreghi, Zeinab, David Haziza, and Christian Léger. 2016. “A Survey of Bootstrap Methods in Finite Population Sampling.” Statistics Surveys 10 (none). https://doi.org/10.1214/16-SS113.

This blog post provides an introduction that doesn't require much mathematical background:

https://www.practicalsignificance.com/posts/survey-regression-what-we-estimate/

Example R Code
Below is some example R code for estimating standard errors and a confidence interval for a sample like the one you describe, using the 'survey' package in R (as well as the 'svrep' package, which implements some additional bootstrap methods).
The first part of the code selects a sample of libraries in the U.S. using unequal probability sampling without replacement. Then it describes the survey design to R using the function svydesign(), and then it creates bootstrap replicate samples and replicate weights.
Finally, it fits a model using the data, where the standard errors are estimated using the bootstrap replicate weights. It shows an example of using the 'survey' package convenience function confint() to estimate a 95% confidence interval. Then it also shows how to calculate that same confidence interval "by hand."
library(survey)
library(svrep)

# Load example data: a census of all public libraries in the U.S. in FY2020

  data("library_census", package = 'svrep')

# Generate sampling probabilities for a sample of size n=200

  sampling_probs <- sampling::inclusionprobabilities(
    a = runif(n = nrow(library_census), min = 1, max = 100),
    n = 200
  )
  library_census[['SAMP_PROB']] <- sampling_probs

# Select a sample using unequal probabilities
  
  sample_indices <- which(
    sampling::UPbrewer(library_census[['SAMP_PROB']]) == 1
  )
  
  selected_sample <- library_census[sample_indices,]
  
# Create bootstrap replicate samples
  
  survey_design <- svydesign(
    data  = selected_sample,
    ids   = ~ 1,
    probs = ~ SAMP_PROB
  )
  
  bootstrap_design <- survey_design |>
    as_bootstrap_design(replicates = 500)
  
# Fit a model and estimate variance using bootstrap replicates
  
  fitted_model <- svyglm(
    design  = bootstrap_design,
    formula = TOTCIR ~ LIBRARIA
  )
  
print(fitted_model)
#> Call: as_bootstrap_design(survey_design, replicates = 500)
#> Survey bootstrap with 500 replicates.
#> 
#> Call:  svyglm(design = bootstrap_design, formula = TOTCIR ~ LIBRARIA)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)     LIBRARIA  
#>       15628        23039  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 199 Total (i.e. Null);  198 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       5.52e+13 
#> Residual Deviance: 2.083e+13     AIC: 5673

# Estimate a confidence interval using the 'survey' package

confint(fitted_model)
#>                  2.5 %   97.5 %
#> (Intercept) -61804.347 93060.13
#> LIBRARIA     -1071.757 47149.44

# Calculate the confidence interval by hand

t_stat <- qt(p = 0.975, df = degf(bootstrap_design) - 1)

cbind(
    coef(fitted_model) - SE(fitted_model) * t_stat,
    coef(fitted_model) + SE(fitted_model) * t_stat
)
#>                   [,1]     [,2]
#> (Intercept) -61804.347 93060.13
#> LIBRARIA     -1071.757 47149.44



Brilliant thanks! I think this is roughly how I've been doing it but I can't be sure. One issue is I couldn't work out how to get a surveyglm() call to itself do the bootstrapping, so I have ended up wrapping surveyglm() calls in my own bootstrap - this has implications for how the weighting is done so I'm not sure if I did it correctly. I'd be interested in relevant example R code!

Ah, ok. I just added some example R code to the post to show what the workflow is for using svyglm() with bootstrap samples. Note that for unequal probability samples, bootstrapping is typically implemented using bootstrap weights. Meaning, in each bootstrap sample, some observations are sampled and then are reweighted a particular way. So you have to use the bootstrap replicate weights for valid estimation.
